# "Load More" table view cell not displaying in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

I'm using Parse's PFQueryTableViewController. After Parse queries my objects and populates the table view, it should display a "Load More" table view cell as the last cell in the table view since pagination is provided by default and is implicitly set to `true`. My problem is that it is not showing up.

I edited my bloated VC into the following code which I deemed relevant. With the configuration below, the "Load More" table view cell is not showing.

```
class ListingsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // PFQueryTableView methods
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
        self.objectsPerPage = 25
        self.parseClassName = "Listing"
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Listing").includeKey("owner")
        query.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
        return query
    }

    // Regular TableView Methods
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 'objects' is a PFQueryTableViewController custom property
        return objects?.count
    }
```

Here are some things I have done:

1. Implemented the `cellForNextPageAtIndexPath` method with a custom table view cell.
2. Implemented the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to 80.0
3. Substituted the `initWithStyle` with the alternative `initWithClassName` method
4. Explicitly set pagination to `true` and objectsperPage to 25 (I have more than 25 objects in my Parse database)

If anyone can find anything wrong with my implementation above I would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, looks like the answer is awfully simple, just don't override the **numberOfRowsInSection** method and let Parse handle it.

When you override this method and return only the number of objects (return objects?.count) then the 1 extra cell needed for "Load more" is missing.